# Maven project couldn't created(Web application) in Netbeans 8.2 JDK8u231

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I tried to create one project on Netbeans. I tried in my personal laptop so Netbeans was fresh install. after installation I opened the IDE and Tried to create new project **NewProject->Maven->WebApplication** but it shows one error that cmd command failed. the build wasn't even started.is there anything to do with maven in netbeans tools->java->maven.

```
Netbeans 8.2
JDK 8u231
```

[This image contain the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q21Q8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use newer NetBeans version? Newest version is NetBeans 11.2: https://netbeans.apache.org/ NetBeans IDE 8.2 was released on 3 October 2016!

Comment: What you have posted is valid as a comment, but doesn't meet the level of an answer. Recommending that the user upgrades might be sound advice, and may be essential for certain _specific_ issues (e.g. JDK 13 not working with NetBeans 8.2), but both students and employees frequently have no control over the software they use. Also, your response does not even consider their _specific_ problem. Also, you are answering their question with your own question, which is hardly appropriate: _Why don't you use newer NetBeans version?_.

Comment: I tried Netbeans 11 but it giving me more problems like now I can't create hibernate projects. I couldn't even find the hibernate library in global libraries. and I tried to add the library but when I do that Its then next issue that I am not able to create hibernate util. and also the java web ee plug in is not showing activate button. but these things were working fine in netbeans 8.2

Answer (score -1):

I've got a similar problem, but an error, I've got some weird characters.
I have a new version of Maven 3.6.0, so I've changed it to "bundled" in option->Java->Maven then Netbeans took his own version (3.0.5) and problem was resolved. Hope it would help [maven version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtXkT.png)

Comment: This is not an answer.